# cron expression for Spring scheduler - run only once a year

Tags: java, spring, cronexpression, spring-scheduled

My Spring service loooks like

```
@Scheduled( cron="0 0  7 * * SUN")
public void doSomething() {
    // do something
}
```

I understand you can't have the 7th value which is reserved for specifying a year. using a expression can I tell spring to just run once a year at a particular time say 25th Dec 6 am in 2020 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can. Just have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665441/cron-expression-for-particular-date) answer. In short, you can use the format:

```
0 0 6 6 9 ? 
| | | | | | 
| | | | | |
| | | | | +----- any day of the week.
| | | | +------- 9th month (September).
| | | +--------- 6th day of the month.
| | +----------- 6th hour of the day.
| +------------- Top of the hour (minutes = 0).
+--------------- Top of the minute (seconds = 0).
```

Comment: The docs state it's only 6 fields.  Indeed, attrempting to add a 7th results in: _"Encountered invalid @Scheduled method ... Cron expression must consist of 6 fields"_ https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

Comment: I've got "invalid cron expression... must consist of six fields..."

Comment: year, Spring doesn't seem to support the year field. but Quartz does: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html.

Answer (score 6):

you can pass month basis it will run only once in year

```
@Schedule(cron="0 0 0 25 12 ?") --- it will run 25th December every year 

public void CronExpression(){

//your logic

}
```

Comment: this will be run in year once you can use this code

Answer (score -1):

Sure

```
@Scheduled( cron="59 59 23 6 12 ? 2020")
public void doSomething() {
    // do something
}
```

This is going to be fired at 23:59:59, December 6 2020