# Execute Laravel Function at a Specified Time

Tags: function, laravel, schedule

How can a function be set to run at a time specified to insert data to a database (date and time)?

When I save data January 30, 2017. The function will run at January 30, 2017,

When I create another data February 01, 2017, then the function will run at February 01, 2017 too.

I tried using Laravel's scheduler but its time must be specified statically, not dynamically, I need a dynamic one so I can customize my date setting.

I tried using Laravel's queue (jobs) but it doesn't have date setting.

Comment: `i must specified time statically, not dynamic` you can read the valyes from database no?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo how if i add new schedule??

Comment: You can use `->cron('0 0 30 1 0 2017');`

Comment: @RaunakGupta can i use it at controller?? or i should foreach each my schedule at schedule (Kernel)??

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code which will run on *January 30, 2017*.

```
//file path: app/Console/Kernel.php
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {

    //other code

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
        $schedule->command('my_command')
                ->withoutOverlapping()
                ->cron('0 0 30 1 0 2017');
    }
}
```

and for *February 01, 2017*

`->cron('0 0 1 2 0 2017')`

---

Reference:

- [Schedule Frequency Options](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options)
- [Cron expression for particular date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3665463/5019802)
- [crontab](http://crontab.guru/)

Comment: How if admin add new schedule at February 11, 2016? it's need to change the Kernel again?

Comment: yes as you want it to be static. and then it will be `0 0 12 11 2 0 2016`

Comment: OK, so the schedule just only can static coded right? cant not date time from database

Comment: if you can save the cron expression in db then loop it and check it works or not. I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems.

Comment: is there any other ways to do a dynamic scheduling system for laravel?