# telegram bot python specific day automated messages

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

**Context:**
I want to add an automated message in my telegram bot i did with python that will send a message every time a specific holiday is eligible. For example, international mans day, independance day etc.
Is this possible without using a json file? Preferably with a simple if function that will compare the current date with a specified one from a list and return a message according to date? I am new in Python if you can direct me to some documentation with an example i would appreciate it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of the special holidays is not too high, you could put the dates and the messages inline in the script like so:

```py
from datetime import date

messages = {
    "03-20": "A message for March Equinox here",
    "09-22": "A message for September Equinox here"
}


def get_message():
    mm_dd = date.today().strftime("%m-%d")
    return messages.get(mm_dd)


print(get_message())
```

If `get_message` returns something other than `None`, pass it to the Telegram bot. Run this from cron once a day.

Answer (score 0):

You could make multiple cron jobs, for each date. Each cron job would run your script and send your message. There is probably a better way to do it. But I personally use cron for all my scripts that execute off a schedule.

Take a look at this for using cron for particular dates:
[Cron expression for particular date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665441/cron-expression-for-particular-date)

You can also use this to easily configure cron schedules:
https://crontab.guru/